# The Hamiltonian cycle problem is P-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I know what P-hard means.
Let's denote the P-hard problem as H. For any problem A in P, there exists a polynomial-time reduction from A to H.
I think the answer is yes (I suppose that every "easy" problem can be reduced to a "harder" problem (in this case problems in P to an NP-complete problem), but I am not sure.

Comment: What is the question?  Make sure to include the question in the body of the post.  Please check the definition of [P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) and P-hard -- does it refer to polynomial-time reductions?  I suggest you include the definition of P-hard that you are using.  "I suspect the answer..." - what answer?  answer to what question?  I notice you've received similar feedback before: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/165166/a-and-b-two-decision-problems-if-a-le-b-then-bar-a-le-bar-b-is-true-if-a#comment343159_165166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hamiltonian cycle problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-Hard (w.r.t. poly-time reductions), that means that there is a Karp reduction from any problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ to Hamiltonian cycle.

Since $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$ the same holds true for any problem in $\mathsf{P}$. Therefore Hamiltonian cycle is $\mathsf{P}$-Hard (w.r.t. poly-time reductions).

Note however, that stronger notions of reductions are often used when talking about $\mathsf{P}$-completeness / $\mathsf{P}$-hardness. Using poly-time reduction yields some "rough" results like: All non-trivial problems in $\mathsf{P}$ are $\mathsf{P}$-Hard.